# Moving MySql from windows server to linux

Tags: mysql

Moving from an old Win2003 server to a new VM server (our choice Win or Linux)
if we go Linux would there be any problems converting the current tables?

Comment: Please don't close this. I posted a viable migration plan.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Moving MySQL/Windows to same version of MySQL/Linux

You can mysqldump all the databases as follows:

```
C:\> mysqldump -uroot -p --routines --triggers --flush-privileges --all-databases > MySQLData.sql
```

Move `MySQLData.sql` to Linux box and run the reload

```
mysql -uroot -p < MySQLData.sql
```

## Moving MySQL/Windows to higher version of MySQL/Linux

You can mysqldump all the databases EXCEPT THE mysql SCHEMA !!! Why?

- MySQL has the grants for the user in a main table called `mysql.user`.
- For each major release of MySQL, `mysql.user` has the following number of columns:

  - 43 columns in MySQL 5.6
  - 42 columns in MySQL 5.5
  - 39 columns in MySQL 5.1
  - 37 columns in MySQL 5.0
  - 31 columns in MySQL 4.0/4.1
- I have discussed `mysql.user`'s column arrangement before

  - `May 01, 2013` : [Can I find out what version of MySQL from the data files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41350/877)
  - `Dec 24, 2012` : [Backup and restore "mysql" database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31023/877)
  - `Jun 13, 2012` : [Fastest way to move a database from one server to another](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19220/877)
  - `Feb 08, 2012` : [will replication from 5.5.20 to 5.0.XX server work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12511/877)

Here is a Windows Batch Script to mysqldump all databases except the mysql schema and then dump the mysql schema in pure SQL:

```
rem
rem Startup Settings
rem
set MYSQL_CONN=-uroot -prootpassword
set MYSQLDUMP_OUTPUT=C:\LocalDump.sql
set MYSQL_USERGRANTS=C:\LocalGrants.sql
set MYSQL_TEMPGRANTS=C:\TempGrants.sql
rem
rem Get MySQL User Data
rem
set MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS=--routines --triggers --databases
set SQLSTMT=SELECT CONCAT('mysqldump %MYSQL_CONN% %MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS% ',DBList)
set SQLSTMT=%SQLSTMT% FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name SEPARATOR ' ') DBList
set SQLSTMT=%SQLSTMT% FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN
set SQLSTMT=%SQLSTMT% ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')) A
echo echo off > C:\RunLocalDump.bat
mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -ANe"%SQLSTMT%" >> C:\RunLocalDump.bat
C:\RunLocalDump.bat > %MYSQLDUMP_OUTPUT%
rem
rem Get MySQL User Grants
rem
set SQLSTMT=SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';')
set SQLSTMT=%SQLSTMT% FROM mysql.user WHERE LENGTH(user)
echo %SQLSTMT%
mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -ANe"%SQLSTMT%" > %MYSQL_TEMPGRANTS%
mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -AN < %MYSQL_TEMPGRANTS% > %MYSQL_USERGRANTS%
del %MYSQL_TEMPGRANTS%
```

Once you create the mysqldump and the Grants File, simply copy them to the Linux Server execute them locally. Execute the mysqldump first. Then, load the grants.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: +1 FWIW, you can run `mysql_upgrade` on the newer version to add needed columns to system tables.  Also, pt-show-grants is a nice tool to export grants for *all* users.

Comment: What would you do to migrate users, their passwords, grants & privileges?

Answer (score 2):

You would not need to convert the tables. The SQL dump from the Windows server would be easy to import into MySQL on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

No the tables will be fine. You should also be able to transfer the config files over without issue

using mysqldump and then just the mysql command to restore the backup

Answer (score 0):

You can export your database (tables with data). Then you will get sql script file. If you run that script file in your new system your tables and data will be available in the new system